# How to disable the authentication popup in chrome browser while wrong password?

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium + Chrome WebDriver (no headles mode). How to disable the authentication popup in chrome browser while wrong password? I need get html page (contain 401 message) but not a popup for try again. My selenuim test suite want check 401 result if password is wrong and 200 OK if password is right.

```
System.setProperty("id", "admin");
System.setProperty("password", "wrongpass");
webDriver.navigate().to(urlToOpen);
```

[image]

***Note n°1 
before responding too quickly:*** If I put a right login/password, I do not have some problem because I do not have Auth popup.

***Note n°2 before responding too quickly:*** I do not have problem with Chrome WebDriver (headles mode) (`chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");`).

Comment: Regarding Breaks Software answer and comments below, I think that you have to correct your question. If I understand correctly, you're not actually interested in the HTTP response code directly, but rather in an error message that the user should see in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Set a tiny timeout to force webdriver to crash after authentication failure

```
Context.getDriver().manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Full code:

```
System.setProperty("id", "admin");
System.setProperty("password", "wrongpass");                 
// Set a tiny timeout to force webdriver to crash after authentication failure
webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
webDriver.navigate().to(urlToOpen);
```

Answer (score 0):

there isn't really a way for you to use Selenium to check what the HTTP response is for a particular request.  If you want to examine the response, you'll need to use code that submits the request directly, like a curl command, and will return a response object that you can examine.  I guess that HttpUrlConnection is the basic tool in Java, but I gather there are many other options depending on the frameworks you might be using (e.g. Spring).

Comment: You did not understand the question. I am not looking for a solution other than selenium. I am in a GUI(HTML Web Interface) test and the authentication popup is blocking my Chrome Webdriver (no headless mode).

Comment: As I stated, I do not believe that there IS a solution with Selenium to get what you are asking for.

Comment: with headless mode i do not have a popup, I looking for same result